# Visual editor toolbar icons not showing on chrome, on some Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: bug

Recently Google Chrome no-more showing any icons on the visual editor tool bar.  On some SE sites (Other browsers unaffected)

Screenshots:

Biology SE

[image: biose].

Chemistry SE

[image: chem se]

Physics SE, Bioinformatics SE, etc.

---

However some other Stack Exchange sites are working nicely, such as:

Meta.stackexchange.com,

[image]

english.stackexchange.com

[image]

etc. ie only some of the sites being affected.

---

How to fix this bug?

---

System information:

Desktop PC, OS: Windows 7 Ultimate.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

## Updates:

As @Rene asked;

Network tab on an affected site, Bio SE
[image: Network tab on Bio SE]

Network tab on an unaffected site, SE Meta
[image: Network tab on META]

(To get larger view, click on image or open them on new tab)

As @Oded asked, no; it is home computer, single, currently running with airtel 3g-4g dongle. And though antivirus being used (would I must disclose?) no "add-blocker" being used.

The link you mentioned, ie.  cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=c776bb8c2bac, i clicked; and it brings to an webpage containing some commands.

The code is quite big to copy-paste; some portion is like below:

`"use strict";StackExchange.mathjaxEditing=function(){function e(){m.disabled=!0,g.resetEquationNumbers()}function t(){m.disabled=!1}function`
 ...  `"SVG":{"EqnChunk":10,"EqnChunkFactor":1}}),b?a(b,"Typeset"):void 0});var k,y=/(\$\$?|\\(?:begin|end)`    ... `var n=e.processError;e.processError=function(i,r,a){return i.message!==t?n.call(e,i,r,a):(MathJax.Message.Clear(0,0),r.jaxIDs=[],r.jax={},r.scripts=[],r.i=r.j=0,r.cancelled=!0,null)},e.Cancel=function(){this.cancelTypeset=!0}}}();`

some portion trimmed as ... ; only first portion, middle portion and end portion shown.

### ----------------------------------------------------------

Update: As @rene asked; I've uploaded screenshot of "security" tab of developer/inspect column.

View when https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js (mentioned in my answer) is not loaded.

[image: mathjax not loaded]

View when https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js has been loaded in another chrome search tab, and then again the stackexchange page reloaded.

[image: when MathJax loaded]

Though it tells "active content with certificate error", not the button "view certificate" shows any certificate error. However on the inspect/developer column of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js shows a certificate error.

[image: Mathjax page with certificate]

---

As well, as @Rene asked; I'm very sorry to say I'm having to use a pirated version of windows (though I'm not really a supporter of this practice). Currently I'm unemployed and my current personal income is too little to buy an original version of windows and ms-office. Also when we bought the computer; we were novice about software installation, and all the software mechanics / technicians  we met ever, were (are) too critic to proceed about original versions. :( Sorry, I'll must buy the original product whenever it will be possible in future.

So incidentally, I don't update windows. (However I don't browse to random sites, and don't download any patch or plugin etc from any third party source. )

Comment: If you open the developer console in your browser (usually F12, then the console tab), so you see any errors when the page is loading?

Comment: @animuson Yes, showing.  On "troubled" branches I'm getting 3 erors. (1) MathJax.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. (2) cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=c776bb8c2bac:1 Uncaught  Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined
    at cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=c776bb8c2bac:1
    at cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=c776bb8c2bac:1 (3). beacon.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. Whereas on "non-troublesome" page, only one error is showing; the third one.

Comment: In the networktab of the dev console can you find MathJax there and shoe us what is says: this is mine working result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2fD9.png

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed? Are you possibly on a corporate/university network that might be blocking these? What happens when you try to access https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/mathjax-editing.en.js?v=c776bb8c2bac directly?

Comment: Your "anti virus" is likely messing with stuff and blocking things it considers "harmful". Disable it and it would most likely solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out a solution; but I am still not very sure whether it is the solution or it is co-incidental. Seems everything happened within chrome's or Google's own privacy features.  (However I need not change any antivirus settings, as well antivirus settings changes did no improved.)

As I was looking the developer ("inspect") tab's network page; there was a button ASK.  (shown in black circle).

[image: ASK]

Now, on clicking this ask button; I was brought to a command or script page; where a command was shown with yellow highlight.

On clicking ask
[image: after clicking ask]

When hovering the mouse pointer over the yellow-highlight-marked line, it was showing "Insecure_Response" (Not screenshoted).

I copied the link ( https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js )from the line, and pasted it on chrome's address bar. After hitting enter; it shown a page with a red coloured triangle containing an exclamation .

"Your connection is nor private"
Back to safety.

[image: Privacy Error]

On the page, I used the "Advanced button" and selected "proceed to ... (unsafe)".

Just after hitting that "proceed" button; on other chrome tabs containing troubled branches;  icons on the visual tool bars appeared suddenly. But "https" with a green lock icon got changed into a red  lock button with a "striked out https".

[image: Striked out HTTPS co occur with icon]

Whatsoever; icons are thus now available; and disappears again if I clean the cookies and history.

Comment: When you have that unsafe connection to cloudflare.com can you again on the dev console go to the tab Security and then screenshot that as well. Just a quick check: Your Windows 7 box is up to date in regard to security patches and other Windows Update required patches?